# Python OpenCV VideoCapturing problem from IP camera..error:(-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number

Tags: python, opencv, url, ip, video-capture

I am trying to enable this IP cam that I have access to its feed by the browser. but can't access it through a python project to do some object detection stuff. but I can't seem to get the feed to be `cv2.videocapture()`ed without an error.
the link to the camera feed is live and working.
the capturing code in the main pythin file:

```
vs = cv2.VideoCapture('http://<user>:<pass>@<IP>:8080/video.cgi?.mjpg')
```

I have tried to put rtsp also but no use and I get this error in the cmd when I run the program by command: anything not in <> is exactly how I entered it

```
[tcp @ 000001f40de13980] Connection to tcp://<IP>:8080 failed: Error number -138 occurred
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (116) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://<user>:<pass>@<IP>:8080/video.cgi?.mjpg in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

1. Streaming laptop camera works `Videocapture(0)`
2. when searching for the port no. in cmd there where 6 internal links so 6 ports I tried all
3. I installed FFMPEG in laptop and added path but not sure if active in the project because I don't know-how

please explain your answer since I'm new and thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score -4):

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@10.10.1.38/H264?ch=1&subtype=0')
ret, im =cam.read()
```

Comment: Please add explanation why this would solve the OPs problem.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28066891)

Comment: hi, this didn't help can you explain what exactly am I suppose to change and why? thank you.